# Recursive function to handle tree json stops in the way

Tags: python, json

I have json tree, nested a few times, but final branch has `answer`.

```
[{
    "selects": [{
            "selects": [{
                "label":"A",
                "answer": "1"
            }]
        },
        {
            "selects": [{
                "label":"B",
                "answer": "2"
            }, {
                "selects": [{
                    "answer": "3"
                }, {
                    "answer": "4"
                }]

            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now I want to change the all value of 'answers'

my current code is like this.

```
def double_answer(i):
    return int(i)*2

def parse(obj):
    #print(obj)
    if type(obj) is list:
        for i in obj:
            #print(i)
            return parse(i)
    else :
        #print(yourObj.keys())
        if 'selects' in obj.keys():
            return parse(obj['selects'])
        if 'answer' in obj.keys():
            obj['answer'] = double_answer(obj['answer'])

def run():
    dict = [{
        "selects": [{
            "selects": [{
                "label":"A",
                "answer": "2"
            }]
        },{
            "selects": [{
                "label":"B",
                "answer": "4"
            }, {
                "selects": [{
                    "answer": "6"
                }, {
                    "answer": "8"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
    parse(dict)
    print(dict)
```

it shows.

```
[{'selects': [{'selects': [{'label': 'A', 'answer': 4}]}, {'selects': [{'label': 'B', 'answer': '4'}, {'selects': [{'answer': '6'}, {'answer': '8'}]}]}]}]
```

Now,first answer in json is changed to 4 (so ,it works for first item!!)

However recursive looks stop here.

I want to change other answers as well.

Comment: What I want is json with doubled answer. I updated the artivle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `return` statement when you're parsing a list:

```
if type(obj) is list:
    for i in obj:
        #print(i)
        return parse(i)
```

This only recurses on the first value in the list, all the others won't be touched. If you want to handle the whole data structure, get rid of the `return`:

```
 if type(obj) is list:
    for i in obj:
        #print(i)
        parse(i)                        # don't return here!
```

Comment: Thank you very much I deleted `return` and solved. It helps me very much.